# Prove that $\sup\limits_nf_n$ and $\inf\limits_nf_n$ are measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\cal{A}$) a measurable space and $f_n : X \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ a sequence of measurable functions.
Prove that $\sup\limits_nf_n$ and $\inf\limits_nf_n$ are measurable.

**Proof:** To prove that a function $f$ is measurable, we have to show that the set $[f \leq b]= \{x \in X : f(x) \leq b\} \in A$ for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$. So

For every $b \in \mathbb{R}$
$$[\sup\limits_nf_n \leq b]=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[f_n 
\leq b] \in \cal{A}$$
and
$$[\inf\limits_nf_n \leq b]=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[f_n 
\leq b] \in \cal{A}$$
But i think that it should be:
$$[\sup\limits_nf_n \leq b]=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}[f_n 
\leq b] \in \cal{A}$$
and
$$[\inf\limits_nf_n \leq b]=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[f_n 
\leq b] \in \cal{A}$$.

Comment: Why do you think the latter should be true?

Comment: \begin{align}&x\in\left\{\sup_nf_n\le b\right\}\\\Leftrightarrow\sup_nf_n(x)&\le b\\\Leftrightarrow  f_n(x)&\le b,\forall n\in\Bbb N\\\Leftrightarrow x&\in\{f_n\le b\},\forall n\in\Bbb N\\\Leftrightarrow x&\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{f_n\le b\}\end{align}

Comment: Also, the same should hold for $\inf\limits_n f_n.$

Comment: @0XLR, I'm pretty sure the author's claim, as currently written, for infimum, is false.

Comment: @Invisible I mean both the latter claims by the OP is false. The first two are correct like you proved above

Comment: The second isn't, I think.

Comment: \begin{align}x&\notin\left\{\inf_nf_n<b\right\}\\\Leftrightarrow 
x&\in\left\{\inf_nf_n\ge b\right\} \\\Leftrightarrow\inf_nf_n(x)&\ge b\\\Leftrightarrow f_n(x)&\ge b,\forall n\in\Bbb N\\\Leftrightarrow 
x&\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{f_n\ge b\}\\\Leftrightarrow  x&\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{f_n<b\}\end{align} That is the only thing where I could see unions. But it isn't the assignment. Intersection should be in both cases.

Comment: @Invisible ya that proves $\{\inf_n f_n < b\} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{f_n < b\}$ what's the issue? It is only intersection in both cases if you flip the inequality for the infimum case like $\{\inf_n f_n > b\} = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \{f_n > b\}$

Comment: @0XLR, okay, silly me, but, without strict inequality? Because, $f_n(x)>b,\forall n\in\Bbb N\not\Rightarrow \inf\limits_nf_n(x)>b$? I see _your_ point, we can't conclude there is interesction  just from $\inf\limits_nf_n(x)\le b$ as I blindly said.